# any way other than AsyncTask?

Tags: android, updating

When i start an activity, i will perform this action

```
webservice.updateallCatNews();
```

This function is retrieve data from online database to local database. The finish time is not constant and depend on internet speed.

I want to know when the action is finished perform. sometime 15, but sometimes 10 or 20. I need to start activity after finished.

Any function can detect the action is finished except asynctask?

```
private class UpdatingNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        webservice.updateallCatNews();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

Activity class

```
private UpdatingNews update;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_formnewuser);
    webservice = new Database_WebService(this);

    update = new UpdatingNews();
    if (isOnline() == true) {
        update.execute("...");

    }
}
```

UpdateallCatNews class

```
public void updateallCatNews() {
    try {
        List<List_CategoryNews> newsCat = dbhelper.getAllNewsCategories();
        for (List_CategoryNews nwCat : newsCat) {

            int CatNewsID = nwCat.getCatID();

            if (CatNewsID != 0) {
                List_CategoryNews deleteNewsCat = new List_CategoryNews(
                        CatNewsID);
                dbhelper.DeleteNewsCat(deleteNewsCat);
            }
        }
        GetNewsCategory();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        b.setMessage(ex.toString());
        b.show();
    }
}
```

Inside this class, there is no others error because other activity can perform.

This if() seem like not running

```
if(update.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING));
```

Why the function

```
webservice.updateallCatNews();
```

not perform?

Comment: You can create a thread and add a Handler to it which passes a message back to your activity when it is finished. Why not just use an AsyncTask?

Comment: Extends a thread and register a delegate (an interface for instance) that your activity implements. Call the callback based on the webservice response

Comment: @DavidScott, i don't know why the `doInBackground()` action cannot perform when i using AsyncTask but `onPostexecute()` it does

Comment: `doInBackground()` runs off the UI thread and `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread. If you post some of your code it will make it easier to work out what's wrong.

Comment: @DavidScott, i had updated the AsyncTask code

Comment: Thanks, can you add the source for `updateallCatNews()` and the code you use to start the AsyncTask. Does the app crash or does it just not call the update method?

Comment: @DavidScott, added again

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread for checking this.Here using a handler you can send messages.By checking the messages You can do the further process.The only possible way to connect thread with the UI is using a handler.I think this piece of code may help you.

```
Thread animator = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                while (i < 4) {
                    sleep(50);
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(i));
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
    animator.start();
    handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub1);
            } else if (msg.what == 1) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub2);
            } else if (msg.what == 2) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub3);
            } else if (msg.what == 3) {
                animatedimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub4);
            }
        }

    };
```